# How to iterate every row(every cell) and check whether the cell contains value or nan, if nan skip row

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have the code like this

```
for r in df.iterrows():
            try:
                if str(r[1][0]) !='nan' and str(r[1][1]) != 'nan' and str(r[1][2]) !='nan' and str(r[1][3]) !='nan' and str(r[1][4]) !='nan' and str(r[1][5]) !='nan':
```

what I need to do is to check if every cell contains a value then only do operation else i need to skip the row, right now I am using 'and' to check every cell, but as we see if there are more columns then i need to put lot of conditionals.

So is there any shortcut way to check (like map or lambda)?

Comment: Both `iterrows()` and lambda/apply are some of the slowest options available. Have a look at `pandas.DataFrame.any()`  in combination with `isna()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with pandas i suggest you to not think of “iterating” because it works a little bit differently...

You should look for a vectorized solution for most of the scenarios because looping in python is slow in comparison to the vectorization numpy and pandas provide...

**SOLUTION**

Here is example to solve your case.

if you want to check only the first 5 columns:

```
df = df[df.iloc[:,0:5].dropna().index]
```

In case there is only 5 rows and you want to check all of them do:

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Note: The above will result in a new dataframe which contains only the necessary data you expect.. you can keep work on this one, keep in mind that following operations should also be vectorized for the privilege of using such libraries